# Стоит ли билдить проект внутренним сборщиком java?

Tags: java, build

Стоит ли билдить проект внутренним сборщиком java?
Если нет то какие есть альтернативы?
Использую IDEA

Comment: Не стоит переписывать вопрос, если уже есть ответы на первоначальную его версию. И на мой взгляд вопрос стал еще более общим, чем был до этого.

Comment: Как я могу вернуть возможность задавать вопросы?
Не пойму что я  делаю не так вроде же можно ответить да стоит билдить или нет не стоит

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7787 . По поводу вашего вопроса - вы скорее всего имеете в виду внутренний сборщик IDEA. Если проектом занимаетесь только вы, если не планируется какой-то автосборки проекта на сервере, автоматического тестирования и деплоя, то можно через IDE собирать и не париться. Но лучше привыкать использовать отдельный сборщик, в ответе к данному вопросу варианты перечислены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ant - старье уже никто его почти не использует
2. Maven - стандарт де факто для web и десктоп Java
3. Gradle - стандарт де факто для Android

> В чём преимущества Gradle

В общем особых нет, кроме того, что его активно лоббирует Google, то есть если ты придешь устраиваться Android прогером то без знания Gradle дальше порога вряд ли пройдешь

Аналогично и с maven, но причина скорее историческая - на серьезный веб прожект без мавена делать особо нечего - есть конечно фанаты с Gradle на вебе - но там пока все очень тухло - какие-то плагины в бета стадии.

Есть более интересные и перспективные билдеры: travis, jenkins, ansible - но это другая история.

Comment: Я спокойно использую gradle для вэб и десктоп проектов (по сути для всего). Какие плагины в бета стадиях? Вы о чём?
И имхо, gradle самый удобный из всех перечисленных (1-3) вариантов.

Comment: Ну для веб я уже давно не писал, так что могу и ошибаться, но в десктопе я так и не смог нормально настроить gradle для javafx - было все очень и очень сыро

Comment: что-то не заметно лобирование гуглом гредла, актуальность версий сильно страдает, да и зачем им это, когда у них своя собственная система сборки есть ?!

Comment: @keekkenen вы серьезно? Достаточно посмотреть на Android Studio, в котором из каждого утюга несется - рекомендуется gradle :)

Comment: рекомендация не значит, что только так и нужно делать, никто не запрещает собирать проект мавеном, базелом, баком и т.п.